# jQuery.post() in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, post

I am currently writing a chatbox plugin for Wordpress.
This plugin uses a jQuery.post() method to send data to a php file in order to write the output to an html file, which in turn will be loaded to the chat window using jQuery.

Inside the php file I use to write the chat log to an html file I need to use Wordpress API functions, but this php file is not included by Wordpress, and therefore has no access to the Wordpress API.

Is there a way to send this chat data to a php file that is included by Wordpress so I can use the Wordpress API? What would be the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: WordPress Codex is a great place: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: @valentinas I have spent the past 2 hours delving through the codex trying to find an answer to my question. I did not find it so I figured I'd try here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wp_localize_script` for sending ajax url in a JavaScript object to the pages:

```
function my_localized_vars() { 
    return array(
      'site_url' => get_bloginfo('url'), 
      'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    );
} 
wp_localize_script('needle', 'object_name', my_localized_vars());
```

Then you can add an action and handle the request.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29

And for getting the url using JavaScript you can code:

```
var url = object_name.ajax_url;
```

Comment: This is a much better approach. My original answer of simply including the wp-blog-header.php file is a pretty lazy method.

Comment: @maiorano84 I usually do not use wordpress, in my last project which was a wordpress theme I found that this way is the standard way for using ajax in wordpress, it worked for me.

Comment: I was complimenting you. This was a good answer, and is the correct method of implementing AJAX Requests.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a separate PHP file, wrap it in WordPress plugin. WordPress Codex will tell you how to [write a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and how to wire it up to [handle your ajax request](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Once you have it working as a  plugin you will be able to access all WordPress APIs.