# Get value of select element use jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery.post() in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924797/jquery-post-in-wordpress)

I want to get the value of select element and use them in PHP. I used jquery to get them out, but I could not pass it to PHP. This is my code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                var team = $("select#team option:selected").val();
                var ath = $("select#athletes option:selected").val();
                var tour = $("select#tour option:selected").val();
                var h = $("#hour").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"?page_id=26&t="+team+"&a="+ath+"&to="+tour
                    }
                }
                )
            });
        });
</script>
```

is there anything wrong? I work this in Wordpress. I thought that the url may be wrong. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: try this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/passing-select-value-to-php-variable check url and try to give full path

Comment: you are using `type:"post"` but setting url for `GET`. Which do you want post or get?

Comment: Also, you should read about how to use Ajax in WordPress https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: You need to read this if your going to use ajax with wordpress: http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#js-global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"<?php echo site_url() ?>?page_id=26&t="+team+"&a="+ath+"&to="+tour
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank Rakesh. I solved it as you said. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
url:"www.mydomain.com?page_id=26&t="+team+"&a="+ath+"&to="+tour
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL needs to be complete. Are you trying to do this on the admin side/user side?

Answer (score 0):

U can do this with this jQuery post method:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            var team = $("select#team option:selected").val();
            var ath = $("select#athletes option:selected").val();
            var tour = $("select#tour option:selected").val();
            var h = $("#hour").val();
            $.post("?page_id=26&t="+team+"&a="+ath+"&to="+tour");
            }
            )
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks alot, Irantha. It worked. Good job!

Comment: @JoeNguyen : You are welcome..so u can mark it as answer ;) at least u can vote :P